# How to use RSpec's should_raise with any kind of exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, rspec

I'd like to do something like this:

```
some_method.should_raise <any kind of exception, I don't care>
```

How should I do this?

```
some_method.should_raise exception
```

... doesn't work.

Answer (score 380, accepted):

```
expect { some_method }.to raise_error
```

**RSpec 1 Syntax:**

```
lambda { some_method }.should raise_error
```

See [the documentation](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.2.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html#M000176) (for RSpec 1 syntax) and [RSpec 2 documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/frames) for more.

Comment: ahh.. I just noticed the curly braces!

Answer (score 88):

#### RSpec 2

```
expect { some_method }.to raise_error
expect { some_method }.to raise_error(SomeError)
expect { some_method }.to raise_error("oops")
expect { some_method }.to raise_error(/oops/)
expect { some_method }.to raise_error(SomeError, "oops")
expect { some_method }.to raise_error(SomeError, /oops/)
expect { some_method }.to raise_error(...){|e| expect(e.data).to eq "oops" }

# Rspec also offers to_not:
expect { some_method }.to_not raise_error
...
```

Note: `raise_error` and `raise_exception` are interchangeable.

#### RSpec 1

```
lambda { some_method }.should raise_error
lambda { some_method }.should raise_error(SomeError)
lambda { some_method }.should raise_error(SomeError, "oops")
lambda { some_method }.should raise_error(SomeError, /oops/)
lambda { some_method }.should raise_error(...){|e| e.data.should == "oops" }

# Rspec also offers should_not:
lambda { some_method }.should_not raise_error
...
```

Note: `raise_error` is an alias for `raise_exception`.

#### Documentation: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec

RSpec 2:

- https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-13/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher

RSpec 1:

- http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Matchers/raise_error
- http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Matchers/raise_exception

Comment: raise_error(/oops/) is a great way to check substring in exception message

Answer (score 86):

Instead of lambda, use expect to:

```
   expect { some_method }.to raise_error
```

This is applies for more recent versions of rspec, i.e. rspec 2.0 and up.

See the [doco](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/dir/matchers/expect-error) for more.

Comment: I wouldn't use this for Rspec 1 but for Rspec 2 it works just as it should.

Comment: Actually, according with the documentation link above, this should be **expect { some_method }.to raise_error**

Comment: Neither your comment nor the page you link to explains why `expect` is better or worse than `lambda`.

Comment: expect is for rspec 2.0 and higher. This renders moot the argument about which one is better, since the lambda syntax doesn't work any more

Comment: This doesn't work for me in capybara: `expect { visit welcome_path }.to raise_error`

Answer (score 66):

The syntax changed recently and now it is:

```
expect { ... }.to raise_error(ErrorClass)
```

Answer (score 6):

From version 3.3 on `rspec-expections` gem raises a warning for a blank raise_error without a parameter

```
expect { raise StandardError }.to raise_error # results in warning
expect { raise StandardError }.to raise_error(StandardError) # fine
```

This gives you a hint that your code may fail with a different error than the test intended to check.

> WARNING: Using the `raise_error` matcher without providing a specific error or message risks false positives, since `raise_error` will match when Ruby raises a `NoMethodError`, `NameError` or `ArgumentError`, potentially allowing the expectation to pass without even executing the method you are intending to call. Instead consider providing a specific error class or message. This message can be supressed by setting: `RSpec::Expectations.configuration.warn_about_potential_false_positives = false`.