# Following rspec exception handling, getting 'NoMethodError' for 'expect'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Confused as to why this RSpec method isn't working. I was looking at the answer here: [How to use RSpec's should_raise with any kind of exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722749/how-to-use-rspecs-should-raise-with-any-kind-of-exception) and have tried all the combinations proposed but for some reason, I'm still getting a NoMethodError.

Here is the exception

```
Exception encountered: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `expect' for #<Class:0x007fa5bd8e4120>>
```

Here is the method:

```
describe "admin should not be accesible" do
expect { User.new(name: "Example Name", email: "email@example.org", password:    "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar", admin: "true") }.should raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
end
```

I got this error earlier so I know that my method is doing what I want it to do:

```
1) User admin should not be accesible
Failure/Error: hey = User.new(name: "Hello", email: "hey@hey.org", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar", admin: "true")
 ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
   Can't mass-assign protected attributes: admin
```

I am running:

RSpec 2.1.0 on Rails 3 with guard-spork 0.3.2 and spork 0.9.0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this is a classic! you are missing the `it` block!

```
describe "admin should not be accesible" do
  it "should bla" do
    expect { User.new(name: "Example Name", email: "email@example.org", password:    "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar", admin: "true") }.should raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
  end
end
```

Comment: In this example, `expect {}.should` has been deprecated, use `expect {}.to`