# rspec/datamapper - how do I tell rspec to expect an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, ruby-datamapper

I'm currently testing this class in Sinatra/Datamapper

```
class Score 
include DataMapper::Resource

property :score, Integer

property :created_at, DateTime, :default => DateTime.now, :lazy => [:show]
property :updated_at, DateTime, :default => DateTime.now, :lazy => [:show]

belongs_to :pageant, :key => true
belongs_to :candidate, :key => true
belongs_to :category, :key => true
belongs_to :judge, :key => true

end
```

with this rspec test

```
it 'that can be inserted by a judge if a pageant is active' do
        score_count = Score.all.length
        post '/score', @correct_score_data
        Score.all.length.should eq score_count+1
    end

    it 'cannot be duplicated if it has been sent' do
        score_count = Score.all.length
        post '/score', @correct_score_data
        Score.all.length.should eq score_count
    end
```

basically what is supposed to happen is that a judge can only send a score for a specific category+candidate+pageant combination once, after which I'm suppose to deny the next scores. Now when I run this I get an IntegrityError (which I expect). How do I tell rspec that I "expect to see this error"? You guys can also critique my code, I'm still learning all of these together

Comment: This will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722749/how-to-use-rspecs-should-raise-with-any-kind-of-exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `expect{}.to raise_error`: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-6/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher

I don't fully understand your specs (it looks like your application state is leaking between the two tests), but something like this...

```
it 'cannot be duplicated if it has been sent' do
    score_count = Score.all.length
    expect { post '/score', @correct_score_data }.to raise_error(IntegrityError)
end
```

Comment: Tried it and yeah it works now. What do you mean the application state is leaking between the two tests?

Comment: Well, the two specs you posted look like they do the exact same thing, but expect different results.  Unless there's more information you didn't post, I assumed you expect one test to run, succeed, and then the next test to run and push the application into the "bad" state.  Two specs shouldn't require each other to work.  If that's not that case, then I just assumed too much!

Comment: Ah yeah what was supposed to happen was that send one, it works, send the same thing, it doesn't work... guess I need to read more